# Switching to a window with no name

Tags: codeception

Using the Codeception testing framework and Selenium 2 module to test a website, I end up following a hyperlink that opens a new window with no name. As a result the `switchToWindow()` function will not work because it is trying to switch to the parent window (which I'm currently on). Without being able to switch to the new window I cannot perform any testing on it.

```
<a class="external" target="_blank" href="http://mylocalurl/the/page/im/opening">
  View Live 
</a>
```

Using both Chrome and Firefox debugging tools I can confirm the new window doesn't have a name, and I cannot give it one because I cannot edit the HTML page I am working on. Ideally I would have changed the HTML to use javascript `onclick="window.open('http://mylocalurl/the/page/im/opening', 'myPopupWindow')` however this is not possible in my case.

I've looked around on the Selenium forums without any clear method to tackle this problem, and Codeception doesn't appear to have much functionality around this.

Comment: Is there a `getWindowNames()` type command in Codeception? I'm sorry I can't seem to find the documentation.

Comment: No there isn't, the documentation is virtually non-existant (although improving over time), however most functions are extensions of Selenium 2 methods. I believe I can execute *some* Selenium 2 methods, but which ones and how many I have no idea. Docs: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Selenium2

Comment: Wow, this is a real pickle. I think the `executeInSelenium` will be your best bet. Looking in the linked to PHP webdriver bindings it does have access to the `getWindowHandle()` and `getWindowHandles()` methods. As such I could only hazard that you `getWindowHandle()` before you open the new window, `getWindowHandles()` after. This will mean you know the two names so you should be able to extract the 'new window' name from the array returned from `getWindowHandles()`. Hopefully it's given you some ideas of the next step as unfortunately I can't fathom how to write a Codeception example.

Comment: Something I have been alerted to and am just about to try: `->executeInSelenium(function (\Webdriver\Session $webdriver) {
   $handles=$webdriver->window_handles(); $last_window = end($handles); $webdriver->focusWindow($last_window);
  });` which I guess is what you are suggesting.

Comment: From what I can see, that's pretty much bang on to what I was hoping. Good luck, hope it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around on the Selenium forum and some helpful prods from @Mark Rowlands, I got it to work using raw Selenium.

```
// before codeception v2.1.1, just typehint on \Webdriver
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $handles=$webdriver->window_handles();
    $last_window = end($handles);
    $webdriver->focusWindow($last_window);
});
```

Returning back to the parent window was easy because I could just use Codeception's `switchToWindow` method:

```
$I->switchToWindow();
```

Comment: Note that when codeception v2.1.1 jumped from facebook/webdriver 0.6.0 to 1.0+, the required signature for this closure changed.  You now have to typehint `\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver`, rather than the `\Webdriver\Session` shown here.  (see https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/2684)

Answer (score 4):

Building on the accepted answer, in Codeception 2.2.9 I was able to add this code to the Acceptance Helper and it seems to work.

```
/**
 * @throws \Codeception\Exception\ModuleException
 */
 public function switchToNewWindow()
 {
    $webdriver = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->webDriver;
    $handles = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $lastWindow = end($handles);
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window($lastWindow);
 }
```

Then in the test class I can do this:

```
$I->click('#somelink');
$I->switchToNewWindow();

// Some assertions...

$I->switchToWindow(); // this switches back to the previous window
```

I had a heck of a time trying to figure out how to do this by just searching google, so I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.   I also had to add        - \Helper\Acceptance  under enabled: in webdriver.suite.yml

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
  WebDriver popup = null;
  Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
  while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
    String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
    popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
  }
```

make sure to return on parent window using,

```
browser.close(); // close the popup.
browser.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle); // Switch back to parent window.
```

I hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Codeception 2.2+ it looks like this:

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $handles = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $lastWindow = end($handles);
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window($lastWindow);
});
```