# Codeception How to interact with a popup

Tags: php, codeception

I have been trying to research how to use Codeception to interact with a checkout modal.

The way the process works is a SPA/view app goes through several pages and builds up the details of a purchase.

When the test/user arrives at the last page they are presented with a 'click and pay' button.  On clicking this button a modal window opens that displays the checkout (its a third party checkout, I cannot change any of the code, manually everything works fine and we need these tests automated.

Once the 'Click and Pay' window opens it presents me with the form and the 'background' window grey's out with a spinner.

When I originally worked on this, it wasn't a problem because the checkout was completed using a redirect, so the user was kept on the same page, no opened windows and would interact as normal.

Please can someone point me in the direction on how I can interact with that page please? filling in all the details is not an issue, its just trying to get focus on the new checkout window.

Answer (score 0):

So after writing that question and using the term 'Focus' I suddenly had a few synapses firing and came across this solution

[[Codeception] Switching to a New Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696303/switching-to-a-window-with-no-name)

Basically it provides a simple script that will take the user to the newly opened window.  A lot of hassle, but I got there in the end